# Adjusting size in geom_smooth() makes legends with different line types look the same

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw six different line types, e.g. like this:

```
d = data.frame(
  x=sample(1:100,30,rep=T),
  y=sample(1:100,30,rep=T),
  exp=rep(c("foo","bar","baz","yak","yaz","bla"),5)
)
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color=exp, lty=exp)) + 
geom_point(alpha=0.15) + 
geom_smooth(size=2)
```

This gives me the following legend:

[image]

Obviously, `size=2` changed the appearance here in such a way that you now cannot discern different line types from each other anymore. Levels 1, 3 and 4 look alike, and so do 5 and 6. When I adjust it to `size=1` (or leave out the size altogether), I get the desired result:

[image]

Is there any way I can get a meaningful representation for different line types in the legend, even when the lines in the plot itself are thicker than the default?

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible. Read the post [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I added a more specific example. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adjusting the `size` or `width` of legend attribute. The examples are taken directly from [**hadley's wiki on legend attributes**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes).

```
# size attribute
theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"))
```

(or)

```
# width attribute
theme(legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"))
```

That is, try this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color=exp, lty=exp)) + 
geom_point(alpha=0.15) + 
geom_smooth(size=2) + 
theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"))
```

Note: You may want to load `require(grid)` if you get `unit()` not found error.

**Edit:** Here's the plot I get with this code, for the example you posted:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color=exp, lty=exp)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.15) + 
    geom_smooth(size=2, se=FALSE) + 
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. This is also the first time I came across the Wiki. Just saw the official documentation before.